# Join on SQL using the most recent data instead of the equal one

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to join 2 dataframes using month and name. However, in one of these dataframes I don't have all the monthly result, so I want to repeat the most recent one.
For example,

```
Dataframe A
name score  month
Alex   20   2020/01
Alex   30   2020/03

Dataframe B
name   month   tenure
Alex  2020/01     1
Alex  2020/02     2
Alex  2020/03     3

Join A+B using name and month - expected result
name   month  score  tenure
Alex  2020/01   20     1
Alex  2020/02   20     2 --> repeat the score from the most recent date
Alex  2020/03   30     3
```

Does someone know how can I do that?

Comment: MySQL has tables, not data frames.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
select b.*,
       (select a.score
        from a
        where a.name = b.name and a.month <= b.month
        order by a.month desc
        limit 1
       ) as score
from b;
```

Or, you can use window functions and a `join`:

```
select b.*, a.score
from b left join
     (select a.*,
             lead(month) over (partition by name order by month) as next_month
      from a
     ) a
     on b.name = a.name and
        b.month >= a.month and
        (b.month < a.next_month or a.next_month is null);
```

This method is convenient if you want to fetch multiple columns from `a`.